# How to wait until Javascript forEach loop is finished before proceeding to next sep

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, foreach, async-await, axios

I need to wait for all of the axios calls in a function called by a forEach loop to run before I call another function to reload data that should be updated by the axios calls.

```
function1() {
    let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    arr.forEach((num) => {
        function2(num);
    });
    //Wait until each call in the forEach loop above
    //is done before running the function3() function.
    function3();
}

function2(number) {
    axios.post('/internal-url/action/' + number)
        .then((response) => {
            return response;
        });
}

function3() {
    console.log('reloading data...');
    /* DB call to reload data */
    console.log('data is reloaded');
}
```

The problem here is that the data reloads before the axios calls are complete. I know the axios calls worked because I can see they updated in the database, but I need for `function1()` to wait for all of the axios calls in `function2()` to finish before running the reload in `function3()`.

I've tried to make `function1()` and `function2()` `async/await` functions, both at the same time and then individually, but that did not work. How would I go about doing this specifically?

Comment: `forEach` is not async. What you want to achieve is the default behaviour

Comment: I don't specifically know about Axios, but the usual way of doing this sort of thing in JavaScript involves "callbacks" that are invoked when, say, an AJAX call completes.  For instance, you might have a counter that's incremented by the `foreach` loop (tracking the number of outstanding requests), then, in the callback that's invoked, subtract 1 from that counter and test for zero.  When it reaches zero, then you call your `function3` ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create an array of promises then use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to await their resolution/rejection using [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await).

```
// async/await - create an array of promises
// from function2, then await until Promise.all has
// fully resolved/rejected
async function1() {
  let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  const promises = arr.map((num) => function2(num));
  await Promise.all(promises);
  function3();
}

function2(number) {
  return axios.post('/internal-url/action/' + number);
}

function3() {
  console.log('reloading data...');
  /* DB call to reload data */
  console.log('data is reloaded');
}
```

Comment: This works. This was really straight forward, and will allow me to do a little research to really understand why/how this works.

Comment: @aCarella: you might want to use `const response = await Promise.all(promises);` and then do something with the `response` data (an array) that's returned. I didn't add that in the answer because it wasn't clear if you were doing anything with it.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution would be to use `Promise.all` so all the requests can be made in parallel. This would look something like this.

```
function1() {
    let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    Promise.all(arr.map((num) => function2(num))).then(() => {
        function3();
    });
}
```

This will wait until all of the promises that `function2` returned have been resolved before calling `function3`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let index = 0;
const answers = [];
(function loop() {
    const value = arr[index];
    function2(value).then(res => {
        answers.push(res);
    });
    index++;
    if (index < arr.length) {
        loop();
    }
})();
function3();
console.log(answers);
```